# keep telling / been telling / telling

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, past-continuous, continuous

If a person or thing( e.g. voicemail) keeps repeating something, or telling me the same thing for a specific time period (e.g. an argument, discussion etc.), which one of the above do I have to use?

For example:

Person A:

*I'll take out the trash after dinner!*

Person B:

*That is what you are telling me for the last 3 days.*

*That is what you have been telling me for the last 3 days.*

*That is what you keep telling me for the last 3 days.*

or

Voicemail :

*We will be with you shortly.*

You(what you're thinking):

*That's what it keeps telling me for 20 min now.*

*That's what it has been telling me for 20 min now.*

*That's what it is telling me for 20 min now.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both your examples, the present continuous versions ("That is what you are telling me for the last 3 days") are definitely incorrect -- because the sentence also has a time reference to a time interval that started in the past and extends until right now, in English it requires present perfect continuous "That is what you have been telling me for the last 3 days", not present continuous. The versions with "keep" sound fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples given, only the [present perfect continuous](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect-continuous/) form is correct. That is, with the ongoing temporal specification, the correct form is:

> Subject + has/have been + verb+ing + ongoing temporal specification
>   I have been waiting since 8 o'clock.
>   I have been waiting for 20 minutes.
>   She has been there since this morning.

Thus:

> That is what *you have been telling me* for the last 3 days.

or

> That's what *it has been telling me* for 20 min now.

The other versions are not correct:

> That is what you are telling me for the last 3 days.
>   That is what you keep telling me for the last 3 days.

However, they do work without the temporal clause:

> That is what you are telling me.
>   That is what you keep telling me.